# Ruby library returns nothing when called from inside vim (filter)

Tags: ruby, vim

I had a filter script that was working earlier today. The script takes lines of chinese characters as input, and outputs Pinyin representation of them (uses the chinese_pinyin gem).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pry'
require 'chinese_pinyin'


STDIN.each_line do |line|
  puts '--------'
  puts line
  puts '--------'
  puts Pinyin.t(line, tonemarks: true)
  puts '--------'
  puts `ruby -v`
end
```

Today my computer stalled (very rare) and rebooted itself. Afterwards, this script will only work on the command line and not from inside vim as a filter.

Command line:

```
benlieb@bens.local 06:28 PM ~/bin >
$ echo "我" | topy
--------
我
--------
wǒ
--------
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin13]
```

Now from inside vim filter one line containing "我" using:

```
:'<,'>!topy
```

I get:

```
  1 --------
  2 我
  3 --------
  4
  5 --------
  6 ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin13]
```

Further inspection shows that

Pinyin.t(line, tonemarks: true)

is returning an empty string in the vim filter case.

The only differences I can see is that vim seems to be receive ASCII-8BIT encoded text and from the CLI it's utf8.

I tried to force utf8 encoding in the script,

```
  line = line.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

but it seems to have no effect:

```
--------
我
ASCII-8BIT
UTF-8
--------

--------
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin13]
```

What is going on and what could cause these scripts to behave so differently?

Comment: Have you enforcing UTF8 in Vim? Instead of the script?

Comment: Also, you may try writing the line to a file then run the script once from the CLI and once from vim and compare the files. Perhaps you'll find there's something else different in the input.